# What is the default association (or mapping) in Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

In Hibernate there are 4 types of mappings:

1. one-to-one
2. one-to-many
3. many-to-many
4. many-t-one

But which is the default mapping?

I performed a web search and found 4 to 5 web sites, but I didn't get the correct answer.

Comment: Please explain clearly what do you mean by "default". Better take an example and rephrase your question. It doesn't seem to make sense as it all depends on the data and entities.

Answer (score 0):

By default, the @ManyToOne and @OneToOne annotations are fetched EAGERly, while the @OneToMany and @ManyToMany relationships are considered LAZY. This is the default strategy, and Hibernate doesn't magically optimize your object retrieval, it only does what is instructed to do.

go through the link: https://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-facts-the-importance-of-fetch-strategy/